# What parts of a modified webpage are retained when returning with the back button?

Tags: javascript, html, standards

I have a page foo.html, which contains input fields and dynamic content. After navigating away from this page and returning with the browser's back button, I've seen inconsistent behavior across various browsers:

- Some return to the initial version of foo.html (no user input, no dynamic content).
- Some return to the final version of foo.html (user input & dynamic content).
- Some return a new version of foo.html (preserving user input but not dynamic content).

**Is there some specified default behavior of how a browser should react or is this "implementation-defined behavior"?**

---

Additional details: Here's the minimal example I used for testing:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="mytext" />
<span id="myspan"></span>

<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Leave</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#mytext").on("input", function () { $("#myspan").text(this.value); });
    });
</script>
```

Text entered in the text box ("user input") is mirrored into the span ("dynamic content"). I have tested it with different browsers with the following results:

- Chrome 58, Edge 40, IE 11 (accessed via http URL): Keeps user input, does not keep dynamic content.
- Firefox 53, Opera Mobile Emulator 12.10: Keeps both user input and dynamic content.
- IE 11 (accessed via file URL): Keeps neither user input nor dynamic content.

Note: I have seen different, inconsistent behaviors when the pages get more complex and AJAX-heavy (e.g. Firefox not retaining dynamic content or IE not retaining user input).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the behavior is standardized (Section 5.6.10 ["History Traversal"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#traverse-the-history) of the HTML5 spec). Unfortunately, it is up to the browsers to decide *which* state is persisted. To quote from Section 5.5 ["Session history and navigation"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#an-entry-with-persisted-user-state) of the spec:

> **An entry with persisted user state** is one that also has user-agent defined state. This specification does not specify what kind of state can be stored.
>
> For example, some user agents might want to persist the scroll position, or the values of form controls.

Thus, all the example behaviors mentioned in your question are valid according to the HTML5 specification.